# laravel forcing users to add additional user info

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am quite new to Laravel and I am making a small test application.
But now I am stuck on the following issue.

After a user logged in to the appilcation I want him/her to see a form where he/her have to fill in more information about him/her self before they can continue.

My problem is that I dont know where to put the code for this, I tried placing it in the Controller.php but it does not seem to work (It does sort of only on the main page but not on the profile page), I also tried to put it in the AppServiceProvider.php as my main menu always recives some data from the database but that also didnt seem to work.

Does any one have an idea where to place the following code ?

```
if (\Request::path() !== 'info' && (\Auth::User()->firstname === NULL || \Auth::User()->lastname === NULL)
{
   return \Redirect::to('info');
}
```

The info page will be the page where the user will see the additional information form.

Comment: Will the user be able to skip this step for this time or does he have to fill out the form to be able to use the application?

Comment: @lukasgeiter He will need to fill it in before visiting any other page but only if the user has a account. Otherwise he can see the pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should create a [middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware) for that.

First run `php artisan make:middleware AccountInfoMiddleware` to create the needed file.

Then open `app/Http/Middleware/AccountInfoMiddleware.php` and add your code to the `handle()` method:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = \Auth::user();
    if($request->path() !== 'info' && $user && ($user->firstname === NULL || $user->lastname === NULL)
    {
        return redirect('info');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

After that you have different ways to use your middleware:

1. Add `App\Http\Middleware\AccountInfoMiddleware` to the `$middleware` array in `app/Http/Kernel.php`. This means the middleware will run for **every request**.
2. Add the same thing with a name to the `$routeMiddleware` in `Kernel.php` and use it for specific routes or enable it from the controller. For more information, visit the [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware)

Answer (score 2):

If you means you want to redirect user if the user dont have firstname and lastname, You can use middleware to solve your problem. Place your code in middleware file.

**Create Middleware file**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware;

class UserMiddleware implements Middleware {

    /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  \Closure  $next
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (\Request::path() !== 'info' && (\Auth::User()->firstname === NULL || \Auth::User()->lastname === NULL)
        {
            return \Redirect::to('info');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Register middleware for route in app/Http/Kernel.php**

```
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * @var array
 */
/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [  
    'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
    'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
    'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
    'user' => 'App\Http\Middleware\UserMiddleware' // Register this new middleware
];
```

**Use that middleware for the route you want**

```
Route::get('/', [  
    'middleware' => 'user',
    'uses' => 'ExampleController@index'
]);
```

After you add the middleware for routes, every request, handle() function inside middleware file will be run to check if the user have firstname or lastname. If the user dont have, it will redirect to info and if the user have all the info, it will process next request.

Comment: Greate explantion only i dont want to do it for every route so i put the code in $middleware instead of $routeMiddleware

Comment: No..you must put in $routeMiddleware.Dont put in $middleware because it will run on each very request. If you put in $routeMiddleware, the middleware will run on the route that you specify. Example Route::get('/login', [ 'middleware' => 'user', 'uses' => 'ExampleController@index'] );. The middleware will run on this route "/login" only.